# ETHERNET STM32F4Discovery with stm32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm using

Software:

-STM32CubeIDE v1.10.1-

-STM32Cube FW_F4 V1.27.1

Hardware:

-STM32F4Discovery

-PHY DP83848

-RJ45

I want to implement the Ethernet peripheral in the STM32F407 mcu with RMI mode without RTOS (via polling mode), and I used stm32Cubeide to create the Ethernet project; I just want to ping the board and go from there, but I can't get it to work. I noticed that after many resets of the mcu, the communication can work and I am able to ping. I think that there is a memory issue with the initialization of the LWIP stack. Can anyone give me some solutions to this problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's a "memory issue initializing the LWIP stack"? Have you debugged it is? What kind of memory issue would it be?

Comment: thank you sir for your reply i found the problem here in ethernetif.c

Comment: thank you sir for your reply i found the problem after long debuging session, here in ethernetif.c the   PHYLinkState = DP83848_GetLinkState(&DP83848); i think that the autonegotiation methode always gnot giving me a stable value for the speed and the mode of the ethenet transfert , it works only when it gives me DP83848_STATUS_100MBITS_FULLDUPLEX , so i  forced the PHYLinkState  to be always DP83848_STATUS_100MBITS_FULLDUPLEX  aka '2' by doing this  PHYLinkState= DP83848_STATUS_100MBITS_FULLDUPLEX and then the ping worked greatly